# How does a person distinguish ambiguous meanings?

Tags: vocabulaire

(Warning: swear words and sexual content are in this question).

Learning French is the first time I'm learning a new language; because of this, I don't have any appreciate of how *I* recognize (in English) what meaning to understand a word, when it has multiple meanings. So, now that I am experiencing words in French that have multiple meanings, I don't know how people distinguish between them.

Here are some words I have experienced this with:

- assez
  (eg, "**- Est-ce que tu veux de la glace? - Oui, j'aime assez la glace**";
  does it mean  "*Yes, I like ice cream enough* [but not a great deal, so don't give me too much]",
  or "*Yes, I quite like ice cream!* [so give me plenty, please!]")
- toujours
  (eg, **"Désolé, je suis toujours malade"**;
  does it mean *"Sorry, I'm still sick"*, or *"Sorry, I'm always sick"*)

And now I just discovered a new ambiguous word as I'm reading a [erotic fiction] short story:

- "*Je rentrais du tennis. Comme d'habitude, après une bonne heure
  intense, je suis assez chaud et j'ai envie de **baiser** mon
  copain*"; does he want to kiss his friend, or fuck his friend? Both
  meanings make sense in this context.

My general question is "How does a person distinguish between meanings, when a word has more than one?". In each of these examples, context alone does not seem sufficient. Is this a case where some meanings are just more used than others, but you would have to be immersed in the culture to understand which is more often used? Are there reference resources that can help me understand?

Edit:
A comment indicated that "Désolé, je suis toujours malade" probably does not mean "Sorry, I am always sick", because tout le temps would more commonly be used to express that meaning; thus, context is not the only thing a person uses to distinguish meaning.

Is there a reference that would help me look up information such as "toujours" rarely meaning "still", or tell me how words (and phrases) are *usually* used, unlike a dictionary which lists all meanings of a word without indicating how often they are typically used?

Comment: Using context, like in every language on Earth. In your first example, the tone with which the sentence is said would provide contexte, but it's almost certain that the first meaning is intended. In your second example, there would be a context. But even without context, it's probably the first meaning (for the second, one would more naturally say "tout le temps" instead of "toujours") In the third example, it clearly means she wants to have sex with her boyfriend, consider the context of an erotic novel. And apart from Québec, AFAIK, "baiser" is hardly used with the meaning of "to kiss".

Comment: In any case I don't see how this is a language about French specifically. This problem exists in every natural language.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : for some reason, I'm surprised that context really is the answer, given how confused I am with these sentences, where the two meanings aren't ever, in English, covered by a single word. Did you, by chance, learn English as a second language? If so, do you remember any English words that, at first, you had trouble distinguishing different meanings through context? (I might ask this as an English Language Learners stackexchange question)

Comment: Yes, I learned English as a second language, and yes, I remember when I had (and still do have) sometimes trouble understanding a sentence. It doesn't mean that English is a special language where you need more than context to understand a sentence. It just means I'm not proficient enough to fully understand the context. Context includes how words are usually used.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi aha: your edit to your comment gives me additional information; the information that "tout le temps" is more likely to be said (for the meaning of "always") than "toujours" shows that it's not purely context that helps distinguish ambiguity -- is there a reference that I can look up such information? (And indeed, this short story is for a Québecois audience, so perhaps "to kiss" could have worked). I wonder if there are in fact sentences that truly *are* ambiguous, even considering context.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Au Québec je n'ai jamais entendu qqn. dire _baiser_ pour _donner un baiser/bec_ à qqn. ; ça me surprend ! Merci !

Comment: @Améraldor C'était peut-être en Belgique alors... Ou un autre pays francophone... J'admets sans problème que j'ai pu me tromper.

Comment: I ask myself how do I know these things, aside from contextual cues, is it really that I know that _toujours_ rarely means still, or that _encore_ is better; is it that I know that _baiser_ very rarely means kiss unless there is a reference to a _hand_ or body part or is it that it's more typical with _avoir envie de_ that _embrasser_ would follow for kissing, but wouldn't I end up with collocations about auxiliairy verbs relating to the frequency of topics etc. I would need a lexical cue at _baiser_ that _embrasser_ is more typical with the notion of wanting to kiss... Thanks!

Comment: @Améraldor: indeed, I wonder if such dictionary/reference (that talks about, for example, comparing usage between *baiser* and *embrasser*) even exists! But your comment does present more clarity about this question of "what are the different ways that fluent speakers subconsciously use context to figure out meaning?"

Comment: Najib: I suspect you were thinking about the Belgian expression *donner une baise*. Silph: A well known ambiguous English word is **free**. The context is sometimes not enough to figure out if it means *gratuit* or *libre*, e.g. **free software**.

Comment: @silph Good question, but I agree that it's not specific to French. I notice you don't have a profile at [Language Learning SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) — could be a good place to ask questions about the learning process itself.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I think this question could be about French, if there existed some kind of resource to recommend, that gave me the kind of information that can help me choose the correct meaning. e.g., maybe some kind of reference that compares how often [and in what cases] "assez" means "enough" vs "quite", etc.

Comment: I doubt that there are resources specifically designed to help figuring out which meaning to pick when a word has more than one. Doing it is actually a common situation with most if not all natural languages, as already stated by @Najib yesterday. For example the English adverb *hardly* has at least two opposite meanings, the most intuitive one for foreign learners being archaic. Identifying what means what in some context is part of the basic learning of any language, not just French.

Comment: @Améraldor Un exemple classique de *baiser* pour *donner un baiser:* [Comment s'adresser au pape](https://fr.wikihow.com/vous-adresser-au-Pape) → baiser l'anneau papal, si c'est approprié.

Comment: @Feelew Merci, ça me fait penser au [_baciamano_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/baciamano) dans le Parrain sans doute... je ne parle pas italien, je pensais qu'ils disaient probablement _bacce la manu_ mais peut-être que ds. ce contexte-là c'est le substantif.

Answer (score 4):

> — Est-ce que tu veux de la glace ? — Oui, j'aime **assez** la glace

To a native French, this is clearly enough context:

- “Would you like some ice cream?” “Yes, I like ice cream **quite a bit**”

> « Désolé, je suis **toujours** malade »

Well, this is a bit more ambiguous, but depending on who is saying it, one should be able to quickly decide on the most likely meaning of it, extreme cases being some athletic young person, strongly built but looking tired or greenish *(then we’d lean towards **still sick**)*, or some weak old person struggling to make more than a few steps *(then quite possibly in a semi-permanent state of weakness)*.

Also and importantly, as [Améraldor](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/3177) rightfully pointed out in the comments, the way **toujours** is pronounced would usually be a perfect clue as to how to interpret it:

- Désolé, je suis *TOU-jours* malade ! <sub>(TOU- *louder and/or higher pitched)*</sub>
  Désolé, je suis *TOU-JOURS* malade ! <sub>(TOU-JOURS *louder and/or higher pitched)*</sub>
  Désolé, je suis *touuujouuurs* malade ! <sub>(toujours *longer, sometimes also higher pitched)*</sub>
  → Sorry, I am AL-ways sick!
- Désolé, je suis toujours malade !
  → Sorry, I am still sick!

There has been comments made about a statistical way of finding the meaning of the sentence, claming that the version *“always sick”* would usually be worded *“tout le temps malade”*, so therefore *“toujours malade”* should be *“still sick”*.

I am unsure what dataset was used to make these claims, and they may be valid, but as far as I am concerned, I would use *“toujours”* most of the time. There are therefore limitations to this method, and the tone method pointed out by Améraldor is a lot more reliable in my opinion, since it would work even for particular individual whose choice of words might be off the claimed standard.

> « Je rentrais du tennis. Comme d'habitude, après une bonne heure intense, je suis assez chaud et j'ai envie de **baiser** mon copain. »

Well, after an hour of tennis, and *intense* tennis that is, the need for a two-second interaction through kissing a boyfriend, or more generally a lover, would be a weird one to express. Though the longer type of interaction, the one unambiguously meant here, is also somewhat weird to express to a third-party.

<sub>And as mentioned in the comments below, the verb ***baiser*** is nowadays used mostly, if not exclusively, to indicate **a sexual intercourse**. It is perhaps the only acception used in Europe (I’m not sure, but the comment makes it sound like it), but in Quebec, the other acception (**to give a kiss**) is still used, though not as widely as before, and not in the majority of the cases anymore either. I was pointing in that rought direction when I used the word *unambiguously*, but it might have been a little too discrete to do the work. So here is the full statement. Thanks to [Jeremy Grand](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/17330/).</sub>

Comment: I appreciate the additional explanation on the "toujours" example. It is helping me to realize that, when learning any second language, figuring out meaning based on context is not a straightforward thing to do for all words that have different meanings.

Comment: @silph So true. When learning English, I was struggling to make sense of the words, trying from them to understand the context, or how people that had a different perspective than mine on the world were judging the current situation. Ultimately, it would have been easier to go the other way: we as humans shared a lot more than I thought at the time, and judging on the situation to understand the words might have been an easier way to go. Best of lucks to you with French!

Comment: L'exemple avec toujours malade je me dis qu'un sujet qui n'a pas été abordé c'est comment on le prononce, l'intonation etc. j'ai l'impression qu'en étirant le _toujours_ ou en accentuant ou en rehaussant ses deux syllabes on met l'accent sur l'aspect répétitif, la fréquence etc. Merci !

Comment: @Améraldor Très vrai! Je modifierai sous peu pour inclure cette très pertinente remarque. Merci.

Comment: je pense que pour souligner côté répétitif, `tout le temps` est plus adapté, et sera la forme la plus utilisée.

Comment: @Flying_whale «Tout le temps» est en effet utilisé, mais je ne suis pas certain des proportions d’utilisation. De mon côté, j’utilise bien plus souvent «toujours», du vôtre apparemment c’est «tout le temps» qui l’emporte. Difficile de faire des stats avec deux points de données, et ça ne résout pas la question de l’ambiguïté lorsque qqn utilise «toujours» et que nous sommes la personne devant déchiffrer la signification...

Comment: I like this answer, but I think we should emphasize that, in today's french, `un baiser` as a noun means `a kiss` while `baiser` (verb) is so likely to be understood as `to shag` that almost noone still uses its primary meaning (giving a kiss). `Embrasser` have taken the place for `to kiss`

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, the answer is in your question:

`Is this a case where some meanings are just more used than others, but you would have to be immersed in the culture to understand which is more often used?`

In my Country (Cameroon), French and English are national languages (Here we use to say "Cameroon is bilingual not cameroonians :D ). We also learn German and Spanish at school as `LV 2 = Langue Vivante 2`.

I will underline **Vivante** which means you need to live a language to learn it well.

The two needs of a language are **Grammar** and **Vocabulary** and, I don't believe you will be able to get your Vocabulary from books.